# how can i recreate flutter shrine screen ui (horizontal scroling)

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web, flutter-animation, flutter-test

i want to make a ui screen like shrine with listview and stack (horizontal scroling) 
if there's a widget to help with it it'll be amazing too 
to the one's who don't know what shrine ui look like [ the right screen ]

[image]

here's some that's not working ..

```
Expanded(
          child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: 10,
            shrinkWrap: true,
            physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return Stack(
                  children: List.generate(10, (index) {
                return Positioned(
                  top: (1 * index).toDouble(),
                  right: 50,
                  width: 300,
                  child: MyWidget(),
                );
              }));
            },
          ),
        ),
```

any idea or insight is appreciated
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `ListView.builder` or `ListView` with `shinkWrap: true` and make sure to scrollDirection is horizontal.

If this solution didn’t help you. U can use third-part libraries, so I mean packages, for example:

- [flutter_staggered_animations](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_animations)

Comment: well i'm already including shrink listvB and Axis.horizontal in the question(see the code) .. but yeah as long as no one came with a great solution i will keep your answer